# How to prove angle bisector $\angle A$, is also angle bisector between height $AH$ and diameter $AM$ in circumscribed circle of the triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, angle

How to prove that in  $\triangle ABC$, angle bisector $\angle A$, is also angle bisector between height $AH$ and diameter $AM$ in circumscribed circle of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be a midpoint of the arc $BC$ and $\gamma>\beta$.

If $\gamma=\beta$ then the lines $AM$, $AK$ and $AH$ are the same line and your statement is wrong.

We have:  $\measuredangle AMK=\frac{\alpha}{2}+\beta$ and since $\measuredangle MKA=90^{\circ}$, we obtain $\measuredangle MAK=90^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}-\beta$.

In another hand, $\measuredangle MAH=\measuredangle BAH-\measuredangle BAM=90^{\circ}-\beta-\left(90^{\circ}-\gamma\right)=\gamma-\beta$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$2\left(90^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}-\beta\right)=\gamma-\beta$$ or
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^{\circ}.$$
Done!

Comment: Why we have $\angle AMK = \alpha / 2 + \beta$?

Comment: @Erfan Shohani Because $\measuredangle AMK=\measuredangle AMC+\measuredangle CMK=\measuredangle ABC+\measuredangle CAK=\beta+\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: Why $\angle BAH - \angle BAM = 90^2 - \beta - (90^{o} - \gamma)$

Comment: @Erfan Shohani Let $O$ is a center of our circle. Thus, $\measuredangle BOA=2\gamma$ and since $OA=OB$, we obtain $\measuredangle BAM=\measuredangle BAO=90^{\circ}-\gamma$. From $\Delta BAH$ we'll get $\measuredangle BAH=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle ABH=90^{\circ}-\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

$\angle CBM=\angle CAM$

Comment: What can I do after that? Should I prove $\angle ABH = 
 \angle CBM$? how can I do it?